# Apply function on specific rows of a df_python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

I am trying to apply the following two functions but with applicability only to specific rows of my df.
For example, the function should run only when the value from column1 is populated with the string 'this is a sentence'. In this case, if the value on column1 is found, the functions should run for other two columns but only on the correspondent rows where the value was found in column1.
Like per this example

```
column1                   column2                 column3         output_required
this is a sentence        phrase1                 SENT            SENT phrase1
this is a brand           phrase2                 10              10
no value available        phrase3                 apple           apple
this is a sentence        phrase4                 Fruits          Fruits phrase4
```

My functions are:

```
    #concatenate with value from column 3
col_target = 'column3'
col_restrict = 'column2'

target = df[col_target].tolist()  # this generates a list of lists
restrict = df[col_restrict].tolist()  # this also generates a list of lists


def parse_str_into_list(s):
    if str(s).startswith('[') and str(s).endswith(']'):
        return ' '.join(str(s).strip('[]').strip("'").split("', '"))
    return str(s)
def filter_restrict_words(row):
    targets = parse_str_into_list(row[0]).split(' ', -1)
    restricts = parse_str_into_list(row[1]).split(' ', -1)
    words_to_keep = []
    for word in targets:
        # condition to keep eligible words
        if word not in words_to_keep:
            # if word not in restricts and word not in words_to_keep:
            words_to_keep.append(word)
            print('words to keep')
            print(words_to_keep)


    return ' '.join(words_to_keep)

df['Title'] = df[[col_target, col_restrict]].apply(lambda x: filter_restrict_words(x), axis=1)
df['output_required'] = df['Title'].map(str) + ' ' + df['column3'].map(str)


#and remove duplicates keeping the first occurrence
def uniqueList(row):
    words = row.split(" ")
    unique = words[0]
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() not in unique.lower():
            unique = unique + " " + w
    return unique
df["Correction_Value"] = df["Correction_Value"].apply(uniqueList)
```

At this point, these funtions are running on all the rows of my df.

Comment: What would be the expected output for your example?

Comment: @99_m4n output_required column from the example above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I Understand Correctly:

try via numpy's `where()` method:

```
#import numpy as np
c=df['column1'].str.contains('this is a sentence')
#checking if 'this is a sentence' exists in column1
df['output_required']=np.where(c,df['column3']+' '+df['column2'],df['column3'])
```

**OR**

via `Series.where()` method:

```
c=df['column1'].str.contains('this is a sentence')
#checking if 'this is a sentence' exists in column1
df['output_required']=df['column3'].where(~c, df['column3'] + ' ' + df['column2'])
```

**OR**

via boolean masking and `loc` accessor:

```
c=df['column1'].str.contains('this is a sentence')
#checking if 'this is a sentence' exists in column1
df['output_required']=None
#creating column output_required
df.loc[c,'output_required']=df.loc[c,'column3']+' '+df.loc[c,'column2']
#getting and assigning the value of column3+' '+column2 where condition c satisfies
df.loc[~c,'output_required']=df.loc[~c,'column3']
#getting and assigning the value of column3 where condition c failed
```

output of `df`:

```
    column1             column2     column3     output_required
0   this is a sentence  phrase1     SENT        SENT phrase1
1   this is a brand     phrase2     10          10
2   no value available  phrase3     apple       apple
3   this is a sentence  phrase4     Fruits      Fruits phrase4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask).

```
df['output_required'] = df['column3'].mask(df['column1'] == 'this is a sentence', df['column3'] + ' ' + df['column2'])
```